# Can Sql Server send an email alert if a RAISEERROR has be raised?

Tags: email, sql-server-2008, alerts

is it possible to get the Sql Server 2008 to send an email when a query **RAISEERROR** is thrown .. or at the very least, when a RAISEERROR with a predetermined error code or codes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You associate an SQL Agent "alert" to detect the error, which then sends an email to an "operator" or runs a job.

You use [`sp_add_alert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189531.aspx) but the main info is here: [Monitoring and Responding to Events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191508.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can put a try/catch block in and send an email using database mail.  It'd go something like this:

```
BEGIN TRY
   [...statement(s)...]
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
   EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='MyProfile',
      @recipients='recipient@mydomain.com',
      @subject='Query Error',
      @body='An error occurred during execution of a statement.'
END CATCH
```

You can use @@Error in the CATCH block to detect the specific error level that was thrown.

Here's more on the [**TRY/CATCH statement**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx)
Here's more on [**SQL Server 2008 Database Mail**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175887.aspx)

Comment: Cheers for the answer :) What about an auto way, without having to manually putting that code in each stored proc/query ... like .. some autotrigger event thing?

Comment: Ah, yes.  I'm with you now.  gbn's got it in his answer.  Alerts are the way to go for general purpose things.